# Godot Android App shows me a black screen

Tags: android, export, godot

When i export my game to android using the Godot game engine it doesn't show me any error on the editor but when i run it on android my screen turns black, why is that happening? it shows the Godot logo but the screen turns black

Comment: Export with GLES2.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your Project Setting -> Application -> Run Main Scene option